# WooCommerce rest api return woocommerce_rest_cannot_view always

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have generated a consumer key and consumer secret. The website has SSL installed. I have also installed plugins required for JSON and REST services. This is how the url looks like:

```
https://<url>/wp-json/wc/v1/products
```

If you want to test

```
Consumer Key: ck_8add1dc9101f8793a731d6b9aeaadd319fbedf37
Consumer secret: cs_18980264faa482536874e4544dfce9c090c7e927
```

When I am trying to get(GET) the product details using Basic Auth by using POSTMAN, a Chrome plugin, I get a JSON response like:

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

I have both the READ and WRITE permissions corresponding to the Consumer key.
I'm testing this RestApi on PostMan RestClient and i disabled `SSL certificate verification` on this app settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The API credentials do not have permissions to read data from woocommerce. Please update the permissions from the woo API settings page and make sure the credentials have Read/Write access or at least Read access.